# How to issue Vim commands in command mode (`Enter` not working)

Tags: vim, neovim

I installed neovim with `pkg install neovim`. I then downloaded the latest version of Nvim-R with `curl -L "https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=26482" > NvimR.vmb`. Finally, I opened the file with `nvim NvimR.vmb`.

Now I'm in the editor and I launch the command mode by pressing the `:` key on my keyboard. I then proceed to type `packadd vimball` into the command console. Finally I try to issue the `packadd vimball` command by hitting `Enter` on my keyboard and nothing happens. I look up in the editor panel and notice each time I hit `Enter` the cursor is just being moved around in the editor.

I don't want the cursor to move around in the editor. I want to issue my `:packadd vimball` command. How do I do this?

[image: vim gif]

Comment: Can I suggest you ask this on https://vi.stackexchange.com/? Broadly, I don't think your command is correct (the docs suggest something more like `packadd install <url>`).

Comment: what should happen then? `packadd` loads the package into your runtime, since there is no error I suppose that is exactly what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I see in that gif is precisely what I would expect to see given what you typed.

1. You run `:packadd vimball`<kbd>Enter</kbd>—this does vim’s native packadd command (assuming nvim has that), and then returns you to the editing portion of the screen.
2. Subsequent <kbd>Enter</kbd> presses are equivalent to `j`—move down a line.

All of that said, I dont know of any packages named vimball, but I don’t really work with that format. Perhaps you’ve misunderstood a plugin’s usage or vimball usage? Ask about that stuff on vi.stackexchange.com: we probably have better vi/m experts there.

Comment: You're correct. I was just expecting some type of confirmation after issuing the `:packadd vimball` but there is no such thing. Everything worked as it should've. Just not that intuitive (yet?) to me. Thank you.

Comment: No problem @JasonHunter ; some things are unintuitive. In unix, though, usually silence is success.